# Number of committees?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

Q: "A committee composed of Morgan, Tyler, Max, and Leslie is to select a president and secretary. How many selections are there in which Tyler is president or not an officer?"

I count as $1 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 3 $. First I select Tyler as P (president) in one way, then I can fill the secretary position in 3 ways. OR I can assign Tyler to secretary and fill president in 3 ways.

However, the solutions say 3+6, why?

Comment: In the OR part of your breakdown, Tyler should *not* be an officer, yet you viewed him as secretary (an officer).

Comment: Ah, terminology misunderstanding. Thanks... is an officer president, secretary and all people on committee? Or just some of those roles?

Comment: ChatGPT does not think or apply logic, but strings together words and phases in patterns which match previous texts. So small differences in wording which change questions and their answers can be missed by ChatGPT.

Comment: @saner: Only president and secretary are "officers" in this set-up. So a selection in which Tyler is not an officer is one in which he is not elected to either president or secretary. This means the president and secretary are selected from the other three people, but note order matters, e.g. Max president, Leslie secretary is different from Max secretary, Leslie president.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to simply be $1\cdot3 + 3\cdot2 = 3+6$, which means "the number of ways to chose president (Taylor) and choose secretary from 3 people OR (+) the number of ways to chose president and secreteary withour Taylor (3*2)".